# Mutate MutableLiveData within viewModelScope or not?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

repository.callPermissionRemove(permissionID) is a suspending function which requires a viewModelScope to call within a viewModel. After calling the suspending function in the repository, I would like to reset the MutableLiveData back to null.

May I know what's the difference between these two sets of code and which one should I implement?

Code A

```
    fun callPermissionRemove(permissionID: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            permissionRemoveAPIResponse.value = repository.callPermissionRemove(permissionID)
        }
        permissionRemoveAPIResponse.value = null
    }
```

Code B

```
    fun callPermissionRemove(permissionID: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            permissionRemoveAPIResponse.value = repository.callPermissionRemove(permissionID)
            permissionRemoveAPIResponse.value = null
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Code A` example, line, setting response value to null will get called **before** `repository.callPermissionRemove()` will execute, whereas in the `Code B` example, lines will execute in the same order as written.

That being said, when resetting `MutableLiveData` field to null after use, you might want to consider using `SingleLiveEvent`. Example of it you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/5b661f1800e1e654f07cc54fe87441af), and some more explanation of why and how [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150).

Comment: Do they also finish in the same order? The first starts a suspend call to callPermissionRemove() and then continues on to next instruction, which is setting the value to null.
It might be that callPermissionRemove() finishes very fast and liveData value is set to its return value before it gets reset to null, but that is not guaranteed. Nor likely.
Try debugging with logs in permissionRemoveAPIResponse observer or just after instructions in questions.